# UITableview not resizing with auto layout in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

In my ViewController, i have a separate UIView in which i have added a UITableView.

I have set constraints of the UITableView, with respect to the UIView
`TableView.Top = top + 5`
`SuperView.Bottom = tbleView.Bottom (Const : 8)`

Have NOT set the Height constraint of the TableView

Now when i change the frame of the Bottom View and increase the Height of the Bottom View  in `public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()`

The frame of the View Changes but the UItableview doesnt stretch and expand height wise.

Any Idea whether i am missing anything ?

`

Comment: try:  tableView.Bottom = SuperView.Bottom (Const : -8)

Comment: Could you give more specific detail to describe your issue,  attach some code or provide a illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. may be work for you.

```
 subview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```